# Нужно ли при добавлении семейства шрифтов с помощью @font-face указывать значения по умолчанию для font-weight и font-style?

Tags: css, шрифты

Есть ли какие-то преимущества второго варианта над первым? В чём отличие? Какой вариант использовать?

Первый вариант:

```
@font-face { /* Обычное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
}
@font-face { /* Курсивное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face { /* Полужирное курсивное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
@font-face { /* Обычное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face { /* Курсивное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face { /* Полужирное курсивное начертание */
  font-family: "Exo";
  src: url("path/to/file.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("path/to/file.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше загрузите `ttf` на `https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator` или другой генератор и работайте со сгенерированным кодом.

Подробное введение по работе со шрифтами:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Comment: Вы не написали, почему ваше решение лучше, и вообще не ответили на вопрос. Я ознакомился со статьёй, на которую вы оставили ссылку, и вот цитата оттуда: «_Если вы импортируете несколько значений толщины одного и того же шрифта вы можете указать какая у них толщина/стиль и затем использовать разные значения font-weight/font-style для выбора между ними, вместо того, чтобы называть всех разных членов семейства шрифтов разными именами._». Там также есть ссылка на статью Роджера Джонсона, в которой описывается проблема вашего решения. Кстати, в своих примерах он использует второй вариант.